Large cracks in second floor closet and other signs of movement
I'm in the contingency phase for a single family home built in the 1920s. The current owners have been there for almost 30 years. The house is 4 stories with a basement and a 3rd floor primary (used to be an attic).
I missed some things (or I could have seen it and didn't realize the implications previously) before putting an offer on the house, but luckily, the inspector noted it. He doesn't seem particularly surprised or concerned, but I'm the one that's going to live in the house, so I want to make sure I know what I'm getting myself into.
The second floor towards the garage side has some issues. Here's a picture to illustrate:

There are large cracks in the closet. Right across from this closet is a bathroom, and the door also indicates signs of movement:

The inspector didn't say that he thinks a structural engineer is needed, but I'm strongly considering it. He said if I get one, he's not confident they'd be able to find the root cause and that they might surmise something that may or may not be correct.
What can a structural engineer help me with here? Do you guys have any suspicions on what could be causing this issue and how it can be corrected? I am a bit scared now and may pull my offer, but idk if I'm overreacting to something that might just be inconsequential.
I will chat with my realtor tomorrow afternoon, and see if we can get some info from the seller on this.

Most any house 100+ years old is going to have some settling and uneven floors. The key is the foundation. You need to start at the bottom and check structural integrity all the way up. If the foundation is good and no rot/termites in the framework it might just be shifting and warping of studs. An inspection by a structural engineer might help you sleep better at night. BTW - you might edit your post and click on the mountain and sun icon to post your pictures.

@HoneyDo Thanks. I should have mentioned this in the OP, but the problem area on the 2nd floor is an add on right above the garage -- I think the garage itself was probably also an add on.
The general inspector did look at the foundation, but was confused about whether the foundation was parged or not since all we could see was poured concrete, and he said houses during that timeframe usually don't have a concrete foundation. We did see some cracks on the (presumably) parged concrete that he said was likely due to moisture

@HoneyDo Yeah, I think I might just have a structural engineer to take a look to give me peace of mind. I will try to edit the post with the pic. never posted a pic on SE/SO before :)

Your Home's foundation or your apartment building foundation is sinking and you need to and have the foundation repaired...
